# 500 server error when authorization request includes the scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access`

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

For my external application I have a requirement to retrieve a refresh token without sending the user through the consent flow.

I have tried following the [documentation](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/#additional-scopes) which describes the available scopes and says that using the scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access` will cause the authorization server to return a refresh token without sending the user through a consent flow.

When I make an authorization request with the scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access`, the authorization server is erroring with a 500 error.

When I make the request without the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access` scope my request will succeed, but I will not get a refresh token back.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the context of requesting a `Refresh Token` as part of a `Plugin`?

The original question doesn't specify, but we've had at least one other developer report an issue with requesting a `Refresh Token` when using an `External Application` as part of a `Plugin`.

*(Using an `External Application` to request a `Refresh Token` outside of the context of a `Plugin` is unaffected.)*

Comment: Yes, the authorization request in this case is initiated when a plugin is opened in the browser. My server redirects the browser to the authorization server and if the authorization request includes the scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access` the authorization server will error with a 500

Comment: Okay, that sounds like the same error which other developers have encountered. We'll work with Engineering to sort things out.

Comment: Engineering has deployed a fix for this today. You should now be able to request that a `Refresh Token` be issued when starting the auth flow by including the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/offline_access` scope.